# Rank-Ordered Logit models for partial rankings with time as covariate

Tags: r, machine-learning, ordered-logit

I'm working on a problem which requires a ROL model, the problem is R does not have much support for these in terms of packages and documentation. I want to fit a ROL model to partial rankings with time as a covariate. I've tried the PlackettLuce package (only works with subset rankings), the PLMIX package (has partial rankings, but no covariate functionality), and the ROlogit package (unclear documentation).

Does someone here have experience fitting partial rankings ROL models with covariates? Specifically, in having them run in R.

EDIT:

Adding information on the data as per @awhug's request. The data is a set of rankings of players over time. The rankings are partial (top n), so that not every player is ranked. There are no ties. Moreover, the rankings are over time, and we are looking to see what the final rankings are at time t. A rough way to do this is to attribute weights to the rankings based on their distance in time to the final ranking date, but I think there is a more elegant solution, perhaps with coxph() as suggested by @awhug. Here's an example of the set below, where we have 15 players ranked over a season. The ultimate goal is to create probability distributions for each player's ranking.

```
tibble(
  player_ranking = 1:10,
  ranking_1 = sample(1:15, 10),
  ranking_2 = c(sample(1:15, 5), rep(0, 5)),
  ranking_3 = c(sample(1:15, 7), rep(0, 3)),
  ranking_4 = sample(1:15, 10),
  ranking_5 = c(sample(1:15, 3), rep(0, 7))) %>%
  pivot_longer(ranking_1:ranking_5) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = player_ranking, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(date_of_ranking = c('2022-07-01', '2022-10-10', '2023-01-01', '2023-05-05', '2023-06-01'))
```

Comment: You can implement rank-ordered logit models as a cox regression using the `coxph()` function in the `survival` package. See [Allison and Christakis (1994)](https://statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/AllisonChristakis.pdf). Happy to provide code demonstrating, but regarding your data, do you have repeated observations within individuals over time? Or do you have one set of rankings per individual, collected over time? And are there any ties in the rankings?

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll include an example today. Meanwhile, reading your link. Appreciate this :)

Comment: Do you have more data than this? There's not really enough information in the reprex to consistently estimate scores for each of the players, let alone over time - in some simulations players might only be ranked once if at all, which makes their inclusion in the model hard. In the meantime you can have a [look at an old gist here](https://gist.github.com/awhug/46d5d3dd0723fe4d4c8ec2a557830bad) where I fit a `coxph` model to a similar dataset (albeit with a time factor).

Comment: If you have head-to-head information on your players, you might also consider looking at [this package](https://github.com/lucasmaystre/kickscore)